# Power BI - feature to publish a dashboard locally and access it via the browser within the network

Tags: powerbi

In the publishing options, I'm looking for a feature to publish a dashboard locally and access it via the browser within the network. I have company data I don't want to publish on powerbi.com. Can this be done? Currently using the free version but upgrading to the paid one is not a problem if it has that feature.

Comment: You need Power BI Report Server. It's expensive though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With a PowerBI Pro licence, you can safely host your report on powerbi.com (or embed on your own website), and share it with your colleagues without having to make it public. [More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards)

If that still isn't enough, look up [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/)

Comment: Hello dear, My concern is, I want to publish the report on my PC (on-premise), so how can I deploy the report and access through my web portal or on my local IP. I don't want to use like 192.168.10.10/reportserver  or (app.powerbi.com), I want to use all report on my own web portal with authorization.

Comment: If less than ~400 people in your company need access to your report, then it will be cheaper to buy everyone a PowerBI Pro licence and then use the Embed command to embed the report on your website (it's secure, because only the users you specifically list will have access to the report). Any more than 500 users, and it will be cheaper to take the Power BI Report Server option.